# Error passing User to ForeignKey in Django

Tags: python, django, typeerror

I'm trying to pass a User model as the parameter for a ForeignKey in my models.py file, but I am getting the error `TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'User'`.

Here are my files, please tell me what I'm doing wrong:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Lesson(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    yt_id = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    upvotes = models.IntegerField()
    downvotes = models.IntegerField()
    category = models.ForeignKey('categories.Category')
    views = models.IntegerField()
    favorited = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**populate_db.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from edu.lessons.models import Lesson
from edu.categories.models import Category

users = User.objects.all()

cat1 = Category(1, 'Mathematics', None, 0)
cat1.save()
categories = Category.objects.all()

lesson1 = Lesson(1, 'Introduction to Limits', users[0], 'Introduction to Limits', 'riXcZT2ICjA', 0, 0, categories[0], 0, 0)
lesson1.save() # Error occurs here
```

Answer (score 1):

Using positional arguments here is very confusing and appears to be the cause.

I can reproduce your error by using positional arguments on a `ForeignKey` on one of my own models. Using kwargs solves the problem.

I'm not even interested in looking into why - I have never used confusing positional arguments to populate a model (seems like they would break ALL the time too with confusing messages if you ever modified your model)

Edit: or much worse, a silent error with input fields going to the wrong model fields over time.

Answer (score 0):

from django.contrib.auth import User (forgot exact import call)
author = models.ForeignKey(User)

Edit (additions): I would import the User the way that I stated and use 'author.category' for the other relationships. This has been resolved though by people who know more about Django than I do.

Comment: his way of importing it should be valid

Comment: @BenH thanks for the heads up. I have never called it that way before. The other's are correct about using the kw arguments and passing default values. I was once trying to do the models for a music discography site and there were tons of m2m relationships. The m2m model had to be defined before I input it in another model so the answer was to use models.ManyToManyField('Vocalists') instead of models.ManyToManyField(Vocalists). A newbie mistake I made back then not thinking about the characteristics of an interpreted language.

Answer (score 0):

You should use keyword arguments as well as simply the initialization it by using default field values.

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    yt_id = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    upvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    downvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    category = models.ForeignKey('categories.Category')
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    favorited = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


lesson1 = Lesson(name='Introduction to Limits', author=users[0], description='Introduction to Limits', yt_id='riXcZT2ICjA', category=categories[0])
lesson1.save()
```